# split a string but keep the elements on which I am splitting on

Tags: javascript

I have the following string `<=10 & <20` and I want to split this string so it gives the following results `('<=' '10' '<' '20')` the & is irrelevant because I deal with that in a different area of my code!

this is the solution I have when it is positive numbers

`.match(/(([<=>]+)|(\d+))/ig)` - result: `'<=' '10' '<' '20'`

But the string can also have negative numbers <=-10 & <-20 and the results required from this would be `('<=' '-10' '<' '-20')`. So how would I update the .match above to handle both scenarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the minus to the regex:

```
"<=-10 & <-20".match(/(([<=>]+)|(-*\d+))/ig)
```

gives the result

```
["<=", "-10", "<", "-20"]
```

Comment: will this handle the positive numbers as well because I need the one regex to handle both scenrios

Comment: Yes. Try it. Note Pablo's answer is using ? rather than * is probably the better answer, although both parse the strings with the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `-` with `?` to make it optional before the digits: `/([<=>]+|-?\d+)/ig` (removed unnecesary parenthesis)